# Blender will open external image editors, but not when launched through Steam

Tags: python, texturing

After trying to open an image in Krita from Blender, it wouldn't open anything. No error messages or anything. Went into Blender's installation folder and ran the executable directly, everything was fine.

My issue is that if I run Blender through Steam, the external image editors don't run for whatever reason, but running it from the executable without Steam works just fine. Anybody know why this is?

Running everything on Arch Linux, Nvidia GPU, Intel CPU if that matters.

Comment: "Went into the Steam installation folder and ran the executable directly, everything was fine." - if everything is fine, what's the problem? You should edit the question and describe your situation properly. Forming an actual questions also helps. This is unclear.

Comment: My bad, edited to hopefully make it a little clearer